# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type xxc because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
[{
"id": "1",
"uye_id": "1",
"plaka": "x",
"km": "0",
"yakit_filtresi": "0",
"hava_filtresi": "0",
"polen_filtresi": "0",
"egr_valfi": "0",
"yag_degisimi": "0",
"triger_seti": "0",
"telefon": null,
"tarih": "2023-12-06" }, 
{
"id": "2",
"uye_id": "1",
"plaka": "x",
"km": "1",
"yakit_filtresi": "1",
"hava_filtresi": "1",
"polen_filtresi": "1",
"egr_valfi": "1",
"yag_degisimi": "1",
"triger_seti": "1",
"telefon": null,
"tarih": "2023-12-27"
  }
]
```

This is my json obcect.

I am trying to develop rest api app in C# form. I am getting an error like in the title..

```
byte[] gonder = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", veri);
string islem = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(gonder);
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(islem);
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, CommandMessage>>(islem);  ###ERROR IN THIS LINE
```

How can I fix and how can I use this json array in foreach loop?

Thanks lot.

Comment: Unrelated: MS does explicitly discourage using `WebClient` and urges to use `HttpClient` instead. At least for new code.

Comment: The JSON you've posted looks like an array of objects but you are trying to deserialize into `Dictionary<string, CommandMessage>`. That seems to be wrong. Also I would encourage you to rethink you variable names (plain English names are easier readable).

Comment: The error message is pretty descriptive. Why not deserialize to a `List<CommandMessage>`?